# Batch write failed: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

```json
{
    "tableName": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "FeatureName": { "S": "blah" },
                    "Active": { "BOOL": true }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "FeatureName": { "S": "blahablah" },
                    "Active": { "BOOL": true }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "FeatureName": { "S": "blahblahblah" },
                    "Active": { "BOOL": true }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the json file ('AllFlagsOn.json') I'm trying to read and batch write to my existing "tableName" thats on the dynamoDB.

Here is the main Typescript code that's trying to do the job:

```js
if (appProps.accountName === 'star') {
    new Stack(app, DEV_APP_NAME);
    jsonFilePath = './bin/AllFlagsOn.json';
    
        const file = fs.readFileSync(jsonFilePath, 'utf-8');
        const data = JSON.parse(file);
        const items = data["ect-feed-status"]; 
        const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: 'us-east-1'});

        const command = new BatchWriteCommand({
            RequestItems: {
                'tableName': items.map((item: any) => ({
                    PutRequest: {
                        Item: item.PutRequest.Item,

                    },
                })),
            },
        });
        client.send(command).then((response) => {
            console.log("Batch write succeeded: ", response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Batch write failed: ", error);
        });
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Batch write failed:  ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`

Here is the output from typing JSON.stringify(command):

```
{"middlewareStack":{},"input":{"RequestItems":{"tableName":[{"PutRequest":{"Item":{"FeatureName":{"S":"blah"},"Active":{"BOOL":true}}}},{"PutRequest":{"Item":{"FeatureName":{"S":"blahblah"},"Active":{"BOOL":true}}}},{"PutRequest":{"Item":{"FeatureName":{"S":"blahblahblah"},"Active":{"BOOL":true}}}}]}},"inputKeyNodes":[{"key":"RequestItems","children":{"children":[{"key":"PutRequest","children":[{"key":"Item"}]},{"key":"DeleteRequest","children":[{"key":"Key"}]}]}}],"outputKeyNodes":[{"key":"UnprocessedItems","children":{"children":[{"key":"PutRequest","children":[{"key":"Item"}]},{"key":"DeleteRequest","children":[{"key":"Key"}]}]}},{"key":"ItemCollectionMetrics","children":{"children":[{"key":"ItemCollectionKey"}]}}],"clientCommand":{"middlewareStack":{},"input":{"RequestItems":{"tableName":[{"PutRequest":{"Item":{"FeatureName":{"M":{"S":{"S":"blah"}}},"Active":{"M":{"BOOL":{"BOOL":true}}}}}},{"PutRequest":{"Item":{"FeatureName":{"M":{"S":{"S":"blahblah"}}},"Active":{"M":{"BOOL":{"BOOL":true}}}}}},{"PutRequest":{"Item":{"FeatureName":{"M":{"S":{"S":"blahblahblah"}}},"Active":{"M":{"BOOL":{"BOOL":true}}}}}}]}}}}
```

And here is the output from Describe Table:

```
{

"Table": {

    "AttributeDefinitions": [

        {

            "AttributeName": "FeatureName",

            "AttributeType": "S"

        }

    ],

    "TableName": "tableName",

    "KeySchema": [

        {

            "AttributeName": "FeatureName",

            "KeyType": "HASH"

        }

    ],

    "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",

    "CreationDateTime": "2022-08-01T15:24:38.112000-05:00",

    "ProvisionedThroughput": {

        "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,

        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,

        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1

    },

    "TableSizeBytes": 105,

    "ItemCount": 3,

    "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:blahablahg",

    "TableId": "ididididid",

    "DeletionProtectionEnabled": false

}
```

}

I double checked on the attribute name and data types and they all match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share the output of JSON.stringify(command)

Comment: I have added the output!

Comment: Is your table actually called `tableName`?

Comment: No, I replaces it with tableName for security issues.

Comment: Can you share the output of DescribeTable and remove anything sensitive but ensure they keys are still showing.

Comment: Yes! I updated it again.